# Create my first ERC721 Collectible collection (VS CODE) //Need Advice

Tags: solidity, tokens, erc-721, visual-studio-code

*I want to start developing with Solidity in my Visual Studio Code my first ERC721 Collectible collection so i installed Visuall Studio Code first, then nodejs and npm and in the end Truffles and Ganache.*

**-I work on Window 10 OS
-Nodejs Version is v14.16.0
-npm Version is 7.6.3
-Solidity v0.5.16**

I want my collection to be like cryptokitties project.

Can anyone provide me some step by step advice, some links or youtube videos that can help me understand the process in that ?

Thank in advance!!

Answer (score 2):

You can check out CryptoZombies. It's a very good resource to look into - https://cryptozombies.io/